# Microsoft HTML Help - 64 bit version?

Tags: 32-bit, help-files

I have an abnormally large CHM file with about 10,000 HTM files within it. The person who originally compiled it seems to have used Doxygen to generate it, but I'm having trouble modifying it and then compiling the modified version. I use [WinCHM](http://www.softany.com/winchm/), and it's constantly telling me that it's running out of memory when compiling. After clicking OK about 100 times, the application freezes and crashes. I tried using the normal Help workshop by MS, but even that's spitting out errors after getting to 1,530 MB memory usage. Both of these apps (WinCHM and HTML Help Workshop) are 32-bit. I thought 32-bit apps could use up to 4096 MB? Anyway, I know that both of these apps are closed-source and abandoned. So I need some kind of 32-to-64 converter (I know it sounds silly) or some other way to store information, images, and files in one compiled file on Windows. Thanks in advance.

Comment: CHM files were retired more than 15 years ago, so no, there isn’t a 64-bit version

Comment: @Ramhound: HLP files were retired 15 years ago, CHM files are still supported by current Windows releases.

Comment: Still doesn’t change the fact there isn’t a 64-bit version

Comment: Sure, but is there any other way to store information (rich text), images, and save-able files in heirarchy? Preferably an x86 workaround for CHMs. Or maybe some other platform (not os) entirely. It should work with Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: There is no 64-bit version of HTML Help and you can use something like regular HTML instead.**

Original answer below.

---

People, please don't use HTML Help. It's 2023 and pretty much every Windows device out there has the memory and processing power to open up a web browser and navigate to a literal HTML file, where you can keep your information instead.

In fact this is the more cross-platform (and future-proof!) way of doing things as you have the advantage of macOS and Linux being able to access whatever information you *would* have been providing in CHM format.

Not to mention the proprietaryness and centralization of Windows OS means that Microsoft could remove HTML Help at any time and "just watch the world burn" like they did with the troubleshooting wizards.

Comment: @Destroy666 The answer to the question is that there is, in fact, no 64-bit version of HTML Help available. And notice how in the question I asked if there was "some other way to store information, images, and files"; HTML supports all of that. It even supports the "embedded files" part with base64 embedding.

Comment: That's not in your answer, which sounds more like a rant than anything factual.

Comment: *The fact that regular HTML files are a lot easier to view on every desktop OS in existence than CHMs is true.* Updated answer with TL;DR.